# What foods are considered Mitztamek Veyafe lo?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, cooking-bishul

ADAIR, according to the opinions that one must garuf and katum his oven even if the food is Maachal ben Derusai, he doesn't have to if the food is Mitztamek veRa Lo [the longer you cook it the worse it gets] (in contrast to Mitztamek veYafe lo [the longer you cook it the better it gets).

The Gemara in Perek Kira in Shabbos gives a few foods which are Mitztamek veYafe lo. Are there any modern foods considered in this category (**mentioned by poskim**).

Out of curiosity, is Cholent in that category?

Comment: Isn't any food that is only 1/3 or 1/2 cooked mitztamek veyafe lo? Why else would you still want to cook it the remaining fraction? (Also, please cite the Gemara you mention from Perek Kira, and perhaps note some of its examples.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe the question is what is an example of something that is נתבשל כל צרכו but still מצטמק ויפה לו. (See שו"ע אדה"ז רנג, ט).

Comment: @DoubleAA definitely not. Tosafos in Shabbos 38 is very clear that whether something is or is not mitztamek veyafe lo is not dependent on how cooked it is. He says that water even when not cooked at all because after it is fully cooked is not mitztamek veyafe lo, it has a Din of Eino mitztamek veyafe lo. Mmitztamek veyafe lo depends on whether the food improves after the fully cooked stage!

Comment: what about soup?

Answer (score 3):

Every Rov I have ever spoken to has used Cholent as the ideal example of a Mitztamek veYafe lo.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it came up in conversation all that often! :)

Comment: @DoubleAA When you learn Perek Kirah in the evenings, it does!

Answer (score 3):

In "Shabbos Kehalacha" (Chelek Aleph Perek Ches), Rabbi Yekusiel Farkash defines *mitztamek veyafa lo* as a food that the **individual** benefits from its continued cooking after reaching *nisbashel kol tzorkoy*, regardless of the benefit to the **dish** itself. He gives the example of meat that gets shriveled up and soft through additional cooking; if the meat will be used only for his family he would be happy to have it softer and it is *mitztamek veyafa lo*, however if he is expecting guests it is *mitztamek verah lo* since he wishes to give them presentable portions and not shriveled meat. He extends this to health concerns; if for medical concerns influence how well done the food should be, that will cause it it to be *mitztamek vetov/verah lo*.

In *ha'orah zayin* he deals with foods that are specifically mentioned in *achronim* to be considered *mitztamek vetov lo*, and discuses when an egg would fall under that category.